# Find out the current version and update of an installed application

Tags: powershell

I have some requirement where I have to find out the *current version* and *update details* of an installed application (highlighted):

[image]

And I have this PowerShell snippet for modification:

```
$server="XXXXXXXXXX"

$ServiceInfo = Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName $server -ExpandProperty Version | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "VSTTAgent"} 
if($ServiceInfo.State -eq "Running")
{
    $userAccount = $ServiceInfo.DisplayName.ToString()
    Write-Host ("VSTTAgent service is Running on $server and  $userAccount  ")                  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the product version, you can use the `Get-Item` cmdlet  using the `PathName` property of your `$ServiceInfo` object:

```
$ServiceInfo.PathName.Trim('"') | Get-Item | select -expand VersionInfo | select ProductVersion
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I got the version but how to get other details like updates number which I have highlighted in the screenshot? please suggest.

Comment: I doubt that this is possible at all if vs doesn't expose these information in say the registry or via cmdlet. You probably have to live with the version info which will allow you do determine which update is included.

Comment: Is there any other way by which I can get these information?

Comment: As I wrote: I don't know any other way.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the same as @MartinBrandl, but the WMI-only version.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service -Filter 'Name="VSTTAgent"' -ComputerName $server | ForEach-Object {
    $filter = 'Name="{0}"' -f $_.PathName -replace '\\', '\\'
    $version = (Get-WmiObject CIM_DataFile -Filter $filter -ComputerName $server).Version

    if ($_.State -eq 'Running') {
        $userAccount = $ServiceInfo.DisplayName.ToString()
        Write-Host ("VSTTAgent ($version) service is Running on $server and  $userAccount")
    }
}
```